# Why is the focal length of a camera inextricably linked to a different perspective?

Tags: optics, vision, camera

The human eye can focus on different distances without ever changing the perspective. Why is the change of focal length in a camera, on the other hand, always linked to a change in perspective? Is the behavior of the flexible eye-lens impossible to imitate with an array of lenses?

Edit: I'm talking about cameras going from a wide-angle to tele-photo perspective when going from short to long focal lengths because it also zooms in. The human-eye can also go from short to long focal lengths but doesn't exhibit a change in perspective.
Why are the two always linked in a camera?

Comment: It's probably possible, but very expensive, as flexible, but still high-quality, lenses seem like they'd be pretty hard to come by. As far as imitating it with an array of lenses, you'd see a sharp reduction in image quality from various sources of aberration unless things were very precisely tuned and all the lenses were parabolic (which drives up the cost by a huge amount).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by ‘a change in perspective’?